# Cygwin convention for naming/location of multiple target libraries

Tags: dll, cygwin, shared-libraries, libraries, naming

I'm maintaining a multi-platform project that also compiles for Cygwin. I want to provide libraries and binaries for the 4 different "cygwin-ish" targets

- 32-bit cygwin
- 32-bit mingw
- 64-bit cygwin
- 64-bit mingw

What would be the Cygwin convention for providing all four of these?

There are two parts to this, the binary, let's call it "runner", and the library ("library") which is a dynamically loadable shared library, a DLL.

The user will build a `.dll` for one of the targets by using a cross-compiler or the native one. (S)He will the use the runner, which among other things will load the user provided DLL and the library. Obviously, the target for all three need to match.

Binaries are usually run from `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` of course, and on DLL-platforms dynamic libraries will be loaded from the same place or from a directory in the path. Since the user will also be linking the DLL against the library, a `liblibrary.dll.a` is required, usually stored in `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local/lib`.

There are two major strategies that I can see

1. provide libraries and binaries with different names but in the same locations and,
2. providing libraries and binaries with the same name but in different locations.

Strategy 1 would lead to `/usr/bin/runner-32-cygwin` etc. and libraries and DLL:s will similar naming. Complexities include that the user would need to understand the naming, running "non-natural" named binaries and the different `.dll.a`:s need to reference/point to different DLL:s.

Strategy 2 would lead to complexities in linking and runtime paths including paths like `/usr/bin-32-cygwin` or some such.

Is there a convention or conventional wisdom to handle this? I'd also appreciate any additional ideas and/or thoughts on the matter or corrections to my assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

Strategy #2

32 bit and 64bit are separated anyway

See 
https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/mingw64-i686-bzip2/mingw64-i686-bzip2-1.0.6-4

```
2013-11-26 22:42           0 usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin/
2013-11-26 22:42       66560 usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin/libbz2-1.dll
2013-11-26 22:42           0 usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/
2013-11-26 22:42        6231 usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/bzlib.h
2013-11-26 22:42           0 usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/
2013-11-26 22:42       63176 usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/libbz2.a
2013-11-26 22:42       23040 usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/libbz2.dll.a
```

versus
https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/libbz2-devel/libbz2-devel-1.0.6-2

```
2013-03-07 02:54           0 usr/include/
2013-03-07 02:54        6245 usr/include/bzlib.h
2013-03-07 02:54           0 usr/lib/
2013-03-07 02:54      271704 usr/lib/libbz2.a
2013-03-07 02:54       22586 usr/lib/libbz2.dll.a
```

and https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/libbz2_1/libbz2_1-1.0.6-2

```
2013-03-07 02:54       65043 usr/bin/cygbz2-1.dll
```